# Uniform convergence in the proof of properties of mollifier (Evan's approach)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am still trying to understand Evans' proof on the properties of mollifier.
[image]

In the proof of (iii), 
[image]

I understand that the crux of the proof is that uniform continuous function on compact set is uniform convergence. However, I do not understand why we need a middle space $W$, isn't that working with $V$ enough? What would happen if do not add such a $W$ in between $V$ and $U$? 
I was told that, the idea of having $W$ is that, if we can show convergence in $W$, then automatically we can show convergence in a smaller space.

This is intuitive. But I am not convinced mathematically and I wish to see what would happen without $W$ in the proof.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/217705/9464

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using that $f$ is uniform continuous when restricted to each open $W$ so that $W\subset\subset U$.

Then for all $\delta >0$, there is $\epsilon_0 >0$ so that 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| <\delta$$
whenever $x, y\in W$ and $|x-y| < \epsilon_0$. Now if $x\in V$. Let $\epsilon_0$ be small so that $|y-x|<\epsilon_0 \Rightarrow y\in W$ (it is in general not true that $y\in V$). Then for all $\epsilon <\epsilon_0$,

$$\begin{split}
|f(x) - f^\epsilon(x)| &= \left| f(x) - \int_U f(y) \eta_\epsilon (y-x) dy\right| \\
&\le \int_U |f(x) - f(y)| \eta_\epsilon (y-x) dy \\
&\le \delta  
\end{split}$$

Note that in the second inequality we are using the uniform continuity of $f$ on $W$, not on $V$. As $x\in V$ is arbitrary, $f^\epsilon \to f$ uniformly on $V$.

Remark: The compactness of $V$ is used to guarantee the existence of such a $W$. Indeed, let $d>0$ be such that $d(v, \partial U) > d$ for all $v\in V$ (This $d$ can be found as $V$ is compact. Then let $W = V_{d/2} = \{ x\in U : d(x, V) < d/2\}$. Then $W$ is open and $\overline W$ is compact and is in $U$.

Comment: Im reading it bit by bit. First, "Let $\epsilon_0$ be small so that $|y-x|<\epsilon_0 \Rightarrow y\in W$ (it is in general not true that $y\in V$)." Why is not true $y\in V$?

Comment: $x$ might be very close to the boundary of $V$, so that $y\notin V$. @math101

Comment: ok. my understanding is that, if both $x,y$ are in $V$, then $f$ may not be uniform continuous in some part of $W$

Comment: and in your last remark, what specific theorem is this? Sounds very familiar but I cannot recall it precisely

Comment: @math101 please see the edit.

Comment: yes thanks that was good. But, in regard to the remark, I was thinking about a particular theorem, usually in 2nd year analysis class...

Comment: on $d(x,V)<d/2$, why not $\le$?

Comment: @math101 I want to make $W$ so that it is open.

Comment: Just to clarify, $f$ is uniform continuous on $W$. But the uniform limit is found on $V$, i.e. $f^{\epsilon}\to f$ uniformly on $V$, $V$ is that compact subset of $U$ Evans' meant. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. @math101

Comment: Actually, I have seen similar answer in some other pde notes. I never went to a PDE class before. And I have to self-study lots for my research. Your answer contains more information than Evan's book. May I ask that, are they from what you learnt in class? (I mean notes from your lecturers, or whiteboard etc)

Comment: I didn't really learn these in classes. I think I learn that when one of my classmate presented the book by Gilbarg and Trudinger in a seminar. And then I read the book again sometimes later. @math101 . I think I learnt a lot when I try to answer question here in math SE too.

Comment: Could you explain how you find  $d>0$ such that $d(v, \partial U) > d$ for all $v\in V$

Comment: @yumiko...........can you teach me evans pde